# Angular Http get with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I know that has a lot of questions about this, but i tried a lot of tips and the problem persists.

i implement a get that return an observable:

```
public getEstatisticasPara(motorista:Motorista): Observable<EstatisticaAvaliacao> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set(Config.ESTATISTICA_AVALIACAO_REQUEST_PARAM, motorista.getId().toString());

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, params: params });

    return this.http.get(this.path, options)
                    .map((res) => res.json) 
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When i try to subscribe always get a undefined:

```
 atualizaMediaAvalicaoes(){
  let motorista:Motorista = FlyweightFactory.getInstanceOf("motorista");
  motorista.setId(1);
  this.estatisticaAvaliacaoProvider.getEstatisticasPara(motorista)
                                   .subscribe((res)=>{
                                        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                                        let estatisticaAvaliacao:EstatisticaAvaliacao = EstatisticaAvaliacao.fromJson(res);
                                        this.storage.set("mediaAvaliacao", estatisticaAvaliacao.getMedia());
                                    },(err)=>{
                                        console.log(err);
                                    });
}
```

Network console show  correct response... so why the undefined ? =/

Comment: Are you using the old `Http` service or the new `HttpClient` ? And how does your `res` object looks like ? Because `res.json` seems strange.

Comment: Http: import { Http} from '@angular/http'; - i think is the old .. the rest response is : {"total":8,"totalCincoEstrelas":2,"totalQuatroEstrelas":3,"totalTresEstrelas":2,"totalDuasEstrelas":1,"totalUmaEstrela":0,"media":3.75}

Comment: Shouldn't this ` .map((res) => res.json)` be this: ` .map((res) => res.json())`. Notice the additional parentheses.

Comment: Yep that's what i ment with `looks strange` :)

Comment: lol..... thats it asuhdsuahdhaudhsaud Thanks.

Comment: So the problem solved ?

Comment: If there's a solution, can the commenter  post the solution as the Answer instead of answering in comments so it can be accepted and the question closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
.map((res) => res.json)
```

should be this:

```
.map((res) => res.json())
```

Notice the additional parentheses.